# Regular Expression Test100-200

Tags: regex

For powershell v3 i need to find items in the range of `Test100` to `Test200`.

For example it should work as this;

```
Test001 - not valid
Test099 - not valid
Test100 - valid
Test150 - valid
Test200 - valid
Test201 - not valid
```

I tried `-match (Test[100,200])` but this does not work.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Test(?:1\d\d|200)\b
```

You can simply use this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hI0qP0/26